# Difference between "That I brought" vs "I brought"

Tags: difference, relative-clauses, ellipsis, subordinate-clauses, optional-that

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> This is a book that I brought from the library.
>
> This is a book I brought from the library.

Do both work? If so why do they both work?

Comment: This topic is addressed in the Wikipedia article [complementizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer). Yes, they both work. Typically, "that" is understood and can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between the two sentences; they convey the same meaning.

The word "that" is a relative pronoun in the relative clause "that I brought from the library".  You can omit the relative pronoun when it's the object of the clause.

I think the sentence without "that" sounds more common and idiomatic.

Comment: I agree except that "that" is not a relative pronoun - it's a subordinator. In both the OP's example, the relative pronoun is missing but represented by the 'gap' notation  ___ : "This is a book (that) I brought ____ from the library".